# How prove this inequality $abc(a^2+b^2+c^2)\le 3$

Tags: inequality

let $a,b,c>0$,and such $$a+b+c=3$$,show that
$$abc(a^2+b^2+c^2)\le 3$$

My idea: since
 $$abc\le\left(\dfrac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^3=1$$
but $$a^2+b^2+c^2\ge \dfrac{1}{3}(a+b+c)^2=3$$
so I can't prove this inequality.Thank you

It is said that can use AM-GM inequality  to solve it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice that
$$ 3(a+b+c)abc(a^2+b^2+c^2) \leq (ab+bc+ca)^2(a^2+b^2+c^2) \leq \left(\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3}\right)^3. $$

The first inequality follows from $a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2 \geq abc(a+b+c)$, which is true as $a^2b^2+b^2c^2 \geq 2ab^2c$, $b^2c^2+c^2a^2 \geq 2abc^2$ and $c^2a^2+a^2b^2 \geq 2a^2bc$ by AM-GM.

The second inequality follows from AM-GM applied on $ab+bc+ca$, $ab+bc+ca$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2$.

Comment: Oh,Nice methods! +1